# How to insert a Word (or cvs) document or Video file to a Word document with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, ms-office

As I continue to develop a larger script (which is working but for this), I can't figure out how to insert a file into a Word document using Applescript. I can insert a picture, but if the file is a Word doc, an Excel spreadsheet, a video file, etc., I can't see in the dictionary where the commands are that would handle that. This example almost works:

```
on AddAttachmentFileToWordDoc(FilePath, Extension)
set GraphicFiles to {"PDF", "jpg", "giff", "TIFF", "gif", "png", "PPM", "PGM", "PNM"}
set VideoFiles to {"mov", "wmv", "amv", "mp4", "m4p", "mpg", "mpeg", "m4v"}
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    tell active document
        set ContTemp to content of text object
        set StartRange to (count of ContTemp) - 1
        set endrange to StartRange
        set theRange to create range start StartRange end endrange
        tell theRange
            if GraphicFiles contains Extension then
                --this works well
                make new inline picture at end with properties {file name:FilePath as text, save with document:true}
            else if VideoFiles contains Extension then
                --this obviously doesn't work, but I would guess that something close to it should.
                make new video at end with properties {file name:FilePath as text, save with document:true}
            else -- everything else, Word docs, excel, etc.
                --make new what?? There is no option for new inline file . . .
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

end AddAttachmentFileToWordDoc

As you can see I have only succeeded with the graphic files. Any ideas what the syntax for the other file types should be? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

The closest I have gotten is by adding, not the file, but a link to the file, like so:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    tell active document
        set ContTemp to content of text object
        set StartRange to (count of ContTemp) - 1
        set endrange to StartRange
        set theRange to create range start StartRange end endrange
        make new hyperlink object at end with properties {text to display:CommentText, hyperlink address:FilePath, text object:theRange}
    end tell
end tell
```